# Selenium WebDriver: I want to overwrite value in field using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver, I want to select the text in the input field and replace it with something else.

I have this code in place.

```
public void renameAGroup(String groupname){
        renameGroupbutton.click();
        renametGroupInput.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"),groupname);
        save.click();
}
```

When I run the above code, it clears the input field and types in the new group name but then it restores the old group name and saves.

Why is the new value being overwritten by the old value?

Comment: Try using `clear()` before send keys and can't you directly use a string in `sendkey()`?

Comment: I have also tried using the renametGroupInput.clear(); renametGroupInput.sendKeys(groupname); but still getting same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a defect in UI thats why the my test was failing.
Once the defect was fixed i was able to use :

```
public void renameAGroup(String name) {
        renameGroupButton.click();
        renametGroupInput.clear();
        renametGroupInput.sendKeys(name);
        save.click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the value attribute using javascript

> JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
>
> executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementid').value =
>   '';");

Tell me if this is working